# Selection sort timer increments time instead of elapsed time

Tags: java, sorting, select

I am timing select sort but timer shows increment time instead of running time.It gives a snapshot of the current count in nanosenconds. Can someone show me why my timing is doing this.
Example:
3741356
3765080
3806116
3850358
3869594
3917684
3940125
3979879
4055540

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class SelectionSortFinal
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Random rand = new Random();
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  int m;
  int n = 0;
  int num_i = 0;
  long startTime = System.nanoTime();  
  long running_time;
  System.out.print("Input array size: ");
  n = input.nextInt();
  System.out.print("Input number of arrays: ");
  num_i = input.nextInt();


  for(int j =  0; j < num_i; j++){

  }
  int array[] = new int [n];
  {

  }
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
      for(m = 0; m < array.length; m++){


           array[m] = (int)(Math.random()*100);

  }
     int temp = 0;
     int min;
     int[] sorted = new int[n];
     for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < (array.length - k); j++) {
         // System.out.println("Start Time: " + startTime);
              startTime = System.nanoTime();

          for (j = 0; j < array.length-1; j++) {

              min = j;

              for ( i = j+1; i < array.length; i++) {
                      if (array[i] < array[min]) {
                              min = i; 
                      }
              }

              if ( min != j ) {
                      temp = array[j];
                      array[j] = array[min];
                      array[min] = temp;

      }
           long endTime = System.nanoTime();
           running_time = endTime - startTime;
          // System.out.println("End Time: " + endTime);
           System.out.println(running_time);
        }


     }

      }

   }
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it's showing time elapsed in nanoseconds. What are you expecting it to show?

Comment: I'm expecting it to show the running time of of each sort, End time - Start time. Its like its showing the time elapsed since the timer started at the first sort instead of the time each sort takes to run.

Comment: @user3403708 - The code is using the same variable `j` in an outer and inner loop. the end time and running time statements need to be moved outside of that loop, (assuming that the start time isn't to be moved inside the loop.